# PHP parsing invalid html

Tags: php, html-parsing, domdocument

i'm trying to parse some html that is not on my server

```
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadHTMLfile("http://www.some-site.org/page.aspx");      
    echo    $dom->getElementById('his_id')->item(0);
```

but php returns an error something like `ID his_id already defined in http://www.some-site.org/page.aspx, line: 33`. I think that is because DOMDocument is dealing with invalid html. So, how can i parse it even though is invalid?

Answer (score 9):

You should run [HTML Tidy](http://php.net/manual/en/book.tidy.php) on it to clean it up before parsing it.

```
$html = file_get_contents('http://www.some-site.org/page.aspx');
$config = array(
  'clean' => 'yes',
  'output-html' => 'yes',
);
$tidy = tidy_parse_string($html, $config, 'utf8');
$tidy->cleanRepair();
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($tidy);
```

See this [list of options](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html).

Comment: tidy is not available for me :(

Comment: @kmunky why not? Without Tidy you're SOL, basically.

Comment: i solved the problem...i have installed php_tidy but i get the following error "ID top already defined in Entity, line: 52"

Comment: Duplicated id's, you'll have to fix them yourself (been there, done that).

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at: libxml_use_internal_errors()

http://php.net/libxml_use_internal_errors

Comment: If you are merely going to recommend a link, please do so as a comment under the question instead of posting as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the docs, I see a `$dom->strictErrorChecking` that defaults to TRUE. What happens if you set `$dom->strictErrorChecking = false`?