# HTML to csv file in php

Tags: php, html, csv

I would like to read a HTML file as and convert the table content inside the html to csv format file using php.

In general, in a directory HTML, i have a list of html files say

```
KMC_Doctors_list_A.html  
KMC_Doctors_list_B.html  
KMC_Doctors_list_C.html  
....
KMC_Doctors_list_Z.html
```

I would like to read these HTML file and the write its table content to a CSV file.

Can any one help me in this regard.

Comment: What have you tried so far? And need more details, do you want the file contents as CSV, or do you want the table contents in the file as CSV?

Comment: What do the HTML files look like, please show us some code.

Comment: `DOmDocuments`, `DOMXpath`, `fputcsv`, and presto....

Answer (score 1):

Get ready for some reading: [fputcsv](http://us.php.net/fputcsv) will write in the csv format. But you need to understand regular expressions [preg_match](http://us.php.net/preg_match) and [preg_match_all](http://us.php.net/preg_match_all) will be very useful in the process. There's no quick way to turn html into csv.

Comment: `fputcsv`: OK, for actually getting the data I'd rather use `DOMDocument` then create a brittle regex-fest.

Comment: Ah of course, html is always impure if you go that route, you need to clean it up: Here's a better discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702799/php-parsing-invalid-html

Comment: please don't recommend regular expressions for what's clearly a HTML parsing job :(