# Getting all the paragraphs in a string extract

Tags: php

I am taking a few paragraphs from a database and try to seperate the paragraphs into an array with regex and different classes..but nothing works.

I tried to do this:

```
   public function get_first_para(){
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($this->review);
    foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
      echo $paragraph."<br/><br/><br/>";
    } 
 }
```

But I get this:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML() [domdocument.loadhtml]: Unexpected end tag : p in Entity, line: 9 in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\bestcamdirectory.com\httpdocs\sandbox\model\ReviewContentExtractor.php on line 18
```

Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in C:\Inetpub\vhosts\bestcamdirectory.com\httpdocs\sandbox\model\ReviewContentExtractor.php on line 20

Why do I get the message, Is there an easy way to extract all the paragraphs from a string?

**UPDATE:**

```
   public function get_first_para(){
         $pattern="/<p>(.+?)<\/p>/i";
         preg_match_all($pattern,$this->review,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
         return $matches;
     }
```

I would prefer the second way..But it doesnt work well too..

Comment: Do you specifically want DOMDocument? You mention regex at one point. The error seems to be saying the document is not valid.

Comment: See this as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702799/php-parsing-invalid-html

Comment: I prefer to use regex actually..cause I want to conserve all the html that is inside those tags

Answer (score 4):

The [DOMDocument::getElementsByTagName](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php) returns a DOMNodeList object which is iterable but not an array. In the `foreach` the `$paragraph` variabl is an istance of [DOMElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domelement.php) so simply using it as a string won't work (as the error explains).

What you want is the text content of the DOMElement, which is available trough the [textContent](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php#domnode.props.textcontent) property of those (inherited from DOMNode class):

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
  echo $paragraph->textContent."<br/><br/><br/>"; // for text only
}
```

Or if you need the full content of the DOMNode you can use [DOMDocument::saveHTML](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php):

```
foreach($doc->getElementsByTagName('p') as $paragraph) {
    echo $doc->saveHTML($paragraph)."<br/><br/><br/>\n"; // with the <p> tag

    // without the <p>
    // if you don't need the containing <p> tag, you can iterate trough it's childs and output them
    foreach ($paragraph->childNodes as $cnode) {
         echo $doc->saveHTML($cnode); 
    }
}
```

As for your loadHTML error, the html input is invalid, you can suppress warnings with:

```
libxml_use_internal_errors(true); // before loading the html content
```

If you need these errors, see the [libxml's error handling part](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) of the manual.

### Edit

Since you insists on regexps here's how you could go about it:

```
preg_match_all('!<p>(.+?)</p>!sim',$html,$matches,PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
```

The [pattern modifiers](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php): `m` means multiline, `s` means the `.` can match line ends, `i` for case insensitivity.

Comment: That isnt good. what it does , it converts everything to string and throws errors along the way...I think i prefer regex

Comment: You can still get the errors with [libxml_get_errors](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php), also see the [html tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/) project for prettying up random html inputs, maybe proves itself useful.

Comment: see my update.. I need to conserve the html elements, so textContent is no good. It doesnt scrape well. I think regex would be a better solution

Comment: I've added an example which will export the DOMNode's html instead of it's text content, i think this is what you wanted. Parsing html with regexpes is [generally a bad idea](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1515540).

Comment: @complex857 I was waiting for a link to that :)

Comment: One must love the classics :-P

Comment: hmm..thanks for your answer.. I prefer to use regex..only need all the paragraphs

Comment: I've added a regexp version that should work in most sane cases, but i still think its a bad idea.