# DOMDocument::load a lot of warnings

Tags: php, domdocument

my problem is that i have a small code, with a large error. can you help me solve this?
i need to make an assignment for school, where i need to get one image from this whole site www.asaphshop.nl
this is my (little) code:

```
<?php
$source = "http://www.asaphshop.nl";
$doc = new DOMDocument("");
$doc->load($source);
echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

these are all my errors:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::load(): error parsing attribute name in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 132 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): attributes construct error in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 132 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Couldn't find end of Start Tag iLength line 132 in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 132 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: input line 144 and script in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 152 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: link line 232 and head in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 333 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Entity 'nbsp' not defined in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 368 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): xmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 465 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): xmlParseEntityRef: no name in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 465 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4

Warning: DOMDocument::load(): Opening and ending tag mismatch: li line 652 and ul in http://www.asaphshop.nl, line: 661 in C:\xampp\htdocs\stage\ripper3.php on line 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Web page on http://www.asaphshop.nl has invalid HTML, so DOMDocument couldn't parse it. Your code is correct.
Try to use another HTML parser.

By the way, there are warnings, not errors. You can get rid of them in `php.ini` settings.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the HTML of http://www.asaphshop.nl is invalid. If you want to print those warnings, you can do it like this:

```
$source = "http://www.asaphshop.nl";
$doc = new DOMDocument("");
@$doc->load($source);
echo $doc->saveXML();
```

if you want to fix the HTML, you can look here: [PHP parsing invalid html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702799/php-parsing-invalid-html)

Comment: thanks, but i need to solve the warnings right? not get rid of them?

Comment: not yet, but there's still no answer on the link you sent me.

Comment: Fatal error: Call to undefined function tidy_parse_string() in

Comment: @Peter: enable tidy module in your php installation

Comment: but how then? just delete the whole part?

Comment: @Peter: What do you mean? Don't you no how to install the tidy? http://scripts.mit.edu/faq/64/how-do-i-enable-additional-php-extensions

Comment: sorry ENable, i thought you said DISable. I'm sorry